# Meaning of "rund um ... etwa"

Tags: meaning, adverb

> Das Skigebiet rund um Oberstdorf etwa ist das höchstgelegene der Region

Why can "etwa" be in that position? What is it modifying? I thought it should be "etwa rund um Oberstdorf" to mean "approximately around Oberstdorf".

Comment: So, if Lars Beck is correct with his answer, I'd say that *etwa* is wrong. "Das Skigebiet rund um Oberstdorf ist **das** höchstgelegene der Region." Aber: "Das Skigebiet rund um Oberstdorf etwa ist **eines** der höchstgelegenen der Welt." Or someone should give me a meaningful context where the sentence as given in the question makes utter sense. I don't see it.

Comment: @Em1  
Imagine some people talking about skiing-areas in the Oberallgäu region and one of them mentions that the one around Oberstdorf is the most altitudinous of them, in this case the sentence makes sense (for example, another one could be the largest).

Comment: @Em1 "Wir haben im Allgäu lauter Superlative! Das Skigebiet ... etwa ist das höchstgelegene der Region!" Dämlich, somit marketinggerecht.

Comment: Kontext: "Von mehreren Skigebieten genießen die höchstgelegenen die stärksten Besucherzahlen und damit Bekanntheitsgrade. Das Skigebiet ..."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case `etwa` means `beispielsweise` *(for example)*, thus the sentence also could be written as below.

> Das Skigebiet rund um Oberstdorf beispielsweise ist das höchstgelegene der Region.

**Update:** I just spotted a mistake in the original example: there's a difference between `höchst gelegen` and `höchstgelegen`, the first one means *very convenient*, the second one *most altitudinous*.

Comment: Correct. The text this sentence comes from starts of with listing different activities one can do in the larger area, then naming Obersdorf as an *example* for a specific place in the area.

Comment: @Lars Hier zeigt sich wieder schön die Idiotie der aus ein ander Schreibung. Habe die Erfahrung bei meinen Kindern gemacht, daß sie grund sätzlich alles aus ein ander schreiben, was nur irgend wie nach mehreren Wörtern aus sieht, obwohl das natürlich so nicht gedacht war. Sieht so aus, als wären sie nicht die einzigen.